# Open a file in VS code using `open -r`

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to use the command `code -r file_name.py` in the integrated terminal in VS code to open the file in the existing window that I'd already opened. However, another new VS code window was still generated. What's weird is that originally, I could open a file by simply using `code file_name.py` without using the `-r` flag. Is there any way to solve the problem? I want the file to be opened in a new tab in the same window instead of in a new window. Any experience shared will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When using VS code the correct command to open a file in an existing code window is indeed `code -r .\file_name.py`, if you are doing so from a terminal within VSCode it will do so within that instance of VSCode.

My instance of VSCode defaults to using CMD on Windows 10 for this command. What are you using to run this command?